# OR Operator in inner join

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

I have query .

```
SELECT  VendorID,VendorName,VendorType,FirstName,LastName,
  VendorCompany,Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,VendorAccountNo ,Photo,VendorNotes FROM 
  Vendor inner JOIN VendorTypeTable ON Vendor.VendorTypeID=VendorTypeTable.VendorTypeID
```

Now on the other side , i want to also retrieve those vendors those have VendorTypeID as null, like this query.

```
SELECT  VendorID,VendorName,FirstName,LastName,
 VendorCompany,Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,VendorAccountNo ,Photo,VendorNotes FROM 
Vendor WHERE VendorTypeID IS NULL;
```

how i can combine these two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Fireblade is absolutely correct, sometimes a UNION is the right answer if you have two queries returning the same fields. This allows you to tweak the performance of each independently of the other.

```
SELECT  VendorID,VendorName,VendorType,FirstName,LastName,  
VendorCompany,Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,
OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,VendorAccountNo ,Photo,VendorNotes FROM 
Vendor inner JOIN VendorTypeTable ON 
Vendor.VendorTypeID=VendorTypeTable.VendorTypeID
UNION
SELECT  VendorID,VendorName,FirstName,LastName, VendorCompany,
Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,
VendorAccountNo ,Photo,VendorNotes FROM 
Vendor WHERE VendorTypeID IS NULL;
```

Comment: You are right . It's working but it does not full fill my requirements. 
I need VendorID, VendorName, VendorType where VendorType field is from VendorTypeTable So, Join is required . But Join does not return those records having VendorTypeID  null .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT vendorid, 
       vendorname, 
       vendortype, 
       firstname, 
       lastname, 
       vendorcompany, 
       contact, 
       phone, 
       altcontact, 
       email, 
       openingbalance, 
       openingdate, 
       vendoraccountno, 
       photo, 
       vendornotes 
FROM   vendor 
       INNER JOIN vendortypetable 
               ON vendor.vendortypeid = vendortypetable.vendortypeid 
                   OR vendor.vendortypeid IS NULL
```

Comment: It does not give right result. Repeats the record many time have vendorTypeID NULL due to join

Comment: @A.RShaib - In that case can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks i got is using UNION .

Comment: @A.RShaib - Then you need to mark John's Union query as **Answer** by selecting the tick mark to the left of his answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use left outer join like this

```
SELECT vendorid, 
       vendorname, 
       vendortype, 
       firstname, 
       lastname, 
       vendorcompany, 
       contact, 
       phone, 
       altcontact, 
       email, 
       openingbalance, 
       openingdate, 
       vendoraccountno, 
       photo, 
       vendornotes 
FROM   vendor 
       left outer JOIN vendortypetable 
               ON vendor.vendortypeid = vendortypetable.vendortypeid
```